# Название контроллера и ресурса в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Почему в Ruby on Rails название контроллера и ресурса должны совпадать? Когда не совпадают, выводится ошибка, что, мол, не видит такого контроллера в папке.

P.S. Rails 4.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду директиву resources в роутах?

Comment: Да да. Это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что при использовании resources имя контроллера, которому передастся запрос, вычисляется автоматом из имени ресурса и, следовательно, должно соответствовать определённым правилам. Помимо этого, рельса создаёт волщебные методы, основываясь на этих именах.

Контроллер, впрочем, можно указать вручную.

```
resources :images, controller: "products_images"
```